# Why it doesn't recognize parameters of a function?

Tags: c++, function

My code is built up with a header file and a .cxx file. In the header there are the declarations of the methods of the class like in the following:

```
virtual EL::StatusCode setupJob (EL::Job& job);
virtual EL::StatusCode fileExecute ();
virtual EL::StatusCode histInitialize ();
virtual EL::StatusCode changeInput (bool firstFile);
std::vector<TH1F*>* CreateHisto (const char* name, const char* title, int nbin, double xmin, double xmax);
virtual EL::StatusCode initialize ();
virtual EL::StatusCode llselection(); 
virtual EL::StatusCode execute ();
virtual EL::StatusCode postExecute ();
virtual EL::StatusCode finalize ();
virtual EL::StatusCode histFinalize ();
```

In the .cxx the function "CreateHisto" is defined:

```
 std::vector<TH1F*>* MyxAODAnalysis :: CreateHisto(const char* name, const char* title, int nbin, double xmin, double xmax) 
{

std::vector<TH1F*>* histo = new std::vector<TH1F*>(m_variations.size());

innermap::const_iterator inner_itmap;  
mainmap::const_iterator itmap; 

for ( itmap = m_variations.begin(); itmap != m_variations.end(); itmap++) {
for (inner_itmap = (*itmap).second.begin(); inner_itmap != (*itmap).second.end(); inner_itmap++) {
            int index = (*inner_itmap).second;              
            std::string nameh = name + ' ' + (*inner_itmap).first;
            const char* namehc = nameh.c_str();                
            histo[index].push_back(new TH1F(namehc, title, nbin, xmin, xmax));
}

}   
return histo; 
}
```

after CreateHisto I have the function called initialize() where I have to initialize a data member called "m_myhisto" to the CreateHisto function and what I'm doing is the following:

```
EL::StatusCode MyxAODAnalysis :: initialize ()
{



m_myhisto = MyxAODAnalysis::CreateHisto(name, title, nbin, xmin, xmax);

return EL::StatusCode::SUCCESS;  
}
```

But in this way it doesn't compile, it gives me the following error:

```
error: ‘name’ was not declared in this scope
m_myhisto = MyxAODAnalysis::CreateHisto(name, title, nbin, xmin, xmax);
```

and so on with the other parameters of the function. 
Why he doesn't recognize them since they are declared in the header?

Comment: Are you asking why parameters of function A are not visible in function B?

Comment: I'm asking why parameters of function CreateHisto declared in the header are not recognize when I call the function in the .cxx.

Comment: Ah. That's because function parameters are effectively local variables in that function. They have nothing to do with calling that function.

Answer (score 2):

as the compiler said: name, should be declared somewhere. 
you are confusing the concept of function protototype and variabile declarations

```
int sum(int x, int y){ return x+y;}

void doSomething()
{
 sum(x,y);
}
```

coud not work

this example work:

```
int sum(int x, int y){ return x+y;}

void doSomething()
{
 int a = 5;
 int b = 6;
 sum(a,b);
}
```

x and y are parameters of the functions
a and b are data passed to the function call.